# What had I become?

Tags: riddle, word

I began as a mild expression of surprise.
At 2, I was a U.S. Army soldier.
At 3, a revolutionary separation expert
At 4, an Aussie child's toy
At 6, a plant with yellow flowers
At 7, more of the same

Then I slept for a few **and became what**?

Comment: Do the numbers relate to the number of characters in the word?

Comment: @Moose I'm just now seeing your comment. Sorry I missed it.

Comment: Well it might not be good practice, but I've had multiple answers deleted or turned into a comment so I honestly have no idea what to make of this site. Corrected.

Comment: @Kingrames I have seen answers turned into comments because they didn't answer the question. If yours did answer the question, partially or fully, then it should have remained an answer, assuming it was well-explained.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Going hamateur was close, but not quite right.

> G = "Gee"  (thanks to Kingrames)
> GI = US Soldier (thanks to Going hamateur)
> GIN = Cotton gin separates cotton (thanks to Going hamateur)
> GING = Australian slang for a slingshot
> GINGER has yellow flowers
> GINGERS more of the same

Final answer is:

> GINGERSNAP = GINGERS plus NAP

Comment: Good. I was less than convinced, got a little stuck on ginkgo... I looked up yellow flowers and hey starts with GIN and is 6 letters... and a flower... But gj man.

Comment: I didn't really mean the first line the way it sounded, mostly I just meant I was building off your work. :P

Comment: I didnt take offense, I was saying I was glad someone cracked it. I was rather displeased with my answer. For ginko extensions I got a bunch of poor examples and gink and australia seemed to have no connection. I did not think I was right. I was more describing this shakespearean tragedy that was my quest into ginkgo, which was in some respect fruitless (unlike ginger plants)

Answer (score 4):

I believe most of it is:

> **G**": as in GEE WILLICKERS BATMAN, credit to Kingrames (I may have missed the hint)
>  **GI**: Military soldier 
>  **GIN**: Cotton gin helped the industrial revolution and separates cotton from seed 
>  GINK: ? 
>  **GINKGO**: Chinese tree with yellow seeds 
>  **GINKGOS**: Same deal

slept for 7 and became:

> **GINKGOSMNP.INC** an HP command injection exploit!

Comment: I concede I did not nail it.

Comment: I think the 4-letter one is [Gino](http://www.fishpond.com.au/Toys/Gino-White-Black-Plush-Music-Ringing-Walking-Panda-Toy-for-Children-Gino/0610256452913).

Comment: You forgot the first one, G, or Gee, as in "Gee whiz!"

Comment: Oh wow I did not even see that as a hint... I am sleepy...